# Aggregate sql resultset into HashBytes value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there an equivalent of

```
CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(*))
```

for HashBytes?

I know you can do

```
SELECT 
    HashBytes('MD5', 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,Field1) + '|' 
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Field2) + '|'
      + CONVERT(VARCHAR,field3) + '|'
    )
FROM MyTable
```

But I am not sure how to aggregate all calculated hashbyte records into a single value inside of SQL.

One reason I would want to do this is to determine if data has changed in the source table since the previous load before moving the data into my system.

Comment: Try doing a hashbyte selection on everything?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you are trying to determine if data changed you should look into [rowversion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of SQL Server, you can use a combination of `CONCAT` and `STRING_AGG` to bung everything together, then hash the whole result.

```sql
SELECT 
    HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',
      STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT(
          CAST(Field1 AS varchar(max)),  -- at least one max
          Field2,
          field3
        ), ''
      )
    )
FROM MyTable;
```

Note that `MD5` is deprecated, and would probably be at risk of hash collisions even in this case. You should use `SHA2_512` or `SHA2_256` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a given row has changed I strongly recomend you to use a "timestamp" column.
The value is automatically updated by Sql Server in every row modification.
Then if a row is changed, the value will be diferent after modification and you could notice it without implementing logic or querying the whole table.

But if you want to know if at least one row has been updated I recomend you to use:

```
DECLARE @Tablename sysname = 'MyTable';

SELECT modify_date FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @Tablename;
```

(If you are using .Net in your business layer it might be interesting for you to take a look on SqlDependency)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all records and combine hashes to one

```
declare @c cursor;
declare @data varchar(max);
declare @hash varchar(400) = '';

set @c = cursor fast_forward for
    select cast(SomeINTData as varchar(50)) + SomeTextData
    from TFact
    where Year = @year
        and Month = @month;

open @c
fetch next from @c into @data
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
    set @hash = HASHBYTES('sha1', @hash + @data)

    fetch next from @c into @data
end

select @hash Ha
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest hashbytes, using a varbinary variable to accrue each row's inner hash results for the final outer hash.
My example below takes ~24 seconds against 870k rows on a mid-range Xeon. More columns and lots of null values will increase crunch time.
The Order by clause is essential to guaranteeing repeatable results.

```
Declare @TableHash varbinary(max) = 0x00;

Select @TableHash =
    hashbytes('MD5', @TableHash +
        hashbytes('MD5',
            isnull(convert(nvarchar(max),Col1_int),'null') + 
            isnull(convert(nvarchar(max),Col2_int),'null') + 
            isnull(convert(nvarchar(max),Col3_int),'null') + 
            isnull(convert(nvarchar(max),Col4_int),'null') + 
            isnull(convert(nvarchar(max),Col5_nvmax),'null'))
        
    )
From MyTable
Order by Col2_int,Col1_int;

Print convert(varchar(max), @TableHash, 1) +
    Case @TableHash When 0x00 Then ' (Table has no data)' Else '' End;
```

Output:

```
0x2AF0A66411F23B67D3819AC407D3B8BD
```